# React-select multiple selects on one page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am a bit confused, here is an example with a couple of select inputs that have the same state, please check here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-selected-by-value-multi-select-react-agamk4?file=src/App.js so please:

- How can I make it so when I select an option the value does not apply to the rest of the select inputs?
- How would you put the values in the store for each of the selects?
- Do I need multiple stores?

For more clarity, here is a screenshot:  https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/19798040?key=bb839c650c93b436066e03d33d5515b0 I hope this makes sense? What would be the best approach? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have shared the code in case of only a single state. You can use this method if you want only a single state but having multiple states for different select inputs also won't be bad as you have only 3 inputs. Having single state method would be useful if number of select inputs would have more.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      value: 1,
      label: 'cerulean',
    },
    {
      value: 2,
      label: 'fuchsia rose',
    },
    {
      value: 3,
      label: 'true red',
    },
    {
      value: 4,
      label: 'aqua sky',
    },
    {
      value: 5,
      label: 'tigerlily',
    },
    {
      value: 6,
      label: 'blue turquoise',
    },
  ];

  // set value for default selection
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState([
    { value: [] },
    { value: [] },
    { value: [] },
  ]);

  // handle onChange event of the dropdown
  const handleChange = (e, no) => {
    setSelectedValue(
      selectedValue.map((item) => {
        return selectedValue.indexOf(item) === no
          ? { value: Array.isArray(e) ? e.map((x) => x.value) : [] }
          : item;
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        className="dropdown"
        placeholder="Select Option"
        value={data.filter((obj) => selectedValue[0].value.includes(obj.value))} // set selected values
        options={data} // set list of the data
        onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, 0)} // assign onChange function
        isMulti
        isClearable
      />
      <br />
      <Select
        className="dropdown"
        placeholder="Select Option"
        value={data.filter((obj) => selectedValue[1].value.includes(obj.value))} // set selected values
        options={data} // set list of the data
        onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, 1)} // assign onChange function
        isMulti
        isClearable
      />
      <br />
      <Select
        className="dropdown"
        placeholder="Select Option"
        value={data.filter((obj) => selectedValue[2].value.includes(obj.value))} // set selected values
        options={data} // set list of the data
        onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, 2)} // assign onChange function
        isMulti
        isClearable
      />

      {selectedValue && (
        <div style={{ marginTop: 20, lineHeight: '25px' }}>
          <div>
            <b>Selected Value: </b> {JSON.stringify(selectedValue, null, 2)}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, what would be the scenario if there are for example 10 select inputs? Is there any way to dynamically set value1, value2, etc, or update the state without too many switch/case? Something maybe with the "name" attribute or?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out and I'm sorry for giving the switch case example. I just forgot about code repetition when answering that. I have updated the solution which is a better way of doing and don't need any kind of repetition.

Comment: Thanks, that's great! I am going to accept the answer!

Comment: One more question if I may add, how can I change/rename this, here is a screenshot: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/19808130?key=3710011a0df893443accb654acf8d469 ?

Answer (score -1):

```
{selectedValue && (
        <div style={{ marginTop: 20, lineHeight: '25px' }}>
          <div>
            <b>Selected Values: </b>
            <span>{
              selectedValue.map(item => item.value.length !== 0 ? 
                <li>{data.filter(data => data.value === item.value[0])[0].label}</li> :
                <li>No value selected</li>
                )
              }</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
```